# Xcode 15 Beta, previewLayout not working doest not display size that fit

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

I'm trying to preview in the canvas the following preview but the modifier `previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)` is not working.

I tried to play with the button at the bottom of the canvas "Live" "and Selectable" but it still does not work.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Custom_Picker: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

#Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout) {
    Custom_Picker()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168042/16157878

Answer (score 5):

Apple got back to me with feedback on this. The new syntax is:

```
    #Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout) {
        DutyTimeViewRow()
    }
```

Comment: 'sizeThatFitsLayout' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer

Comment: To help others, please choose an answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

- Also, you can code like this in xCode 15

  ```swift
  #Preview(traits:.sizeThatFitsLayout){
      DutyTimeViewRow()
          .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375, height: 600))
  }
  ```

Be sure to also choose *Selectable* from the preview.

[image: Be sure to also choose "Selectable" from the preview]

Comment: i tried but not work, my preview still show the full iPhone screen

Comment: You need to use the preview macro like @azermann mentiones.

Comment: With the Selectable trick worked Xcode 15.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

with new preview macro system u just use traits
u can use

```
#Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout) {
    DutyTimeViewRow()
}
```

or for fixed layout

```
#Preview(traits: .fixedLayout(width: 400, height: 220)) {
    DutyTimeViewRow()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found that you can fix this by using the old preview syntax instead of "#Preview" in Xcode 15. Try:

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct DutyTimeViewRow: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }.frame(width:  100)
        }
    }
    
    struct DutyTimeViewRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            DutyTimeViewRow()
                .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        }
    }
```