# Xcode 15: SwiftUI preview layout: size that fits does not work

Tags: swiftui, preview, xcode15

Xcode 14 worked normally but in Xcode 15 it stopped working.

I tried using Xcode 15 preview, .sizeThatFits and .fixed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DhEl.gif

```swift
#Preview {
    AddRegionView()
        .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 100, height: 100))
//        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI preview layout: size that fits does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74429078/swiftui-preview-layout-size-that-fits-does-not-work)

Answer (score 16):

When using the `#Preview` macro, the settings that you would previously attach as modifiers are now added as traits to the macro declaration, e.g.:

```swift
#Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout) {
    ContentView()
}
```

or for a fixed size:

```swift
#Preview(traits: .fixedLayout(width: 100, height: 100)) {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: For anyone who stumbles here, above code requires switching iOS Deployment Target to 17.0 or newer in the project build settings. Some details: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731865

Comment: 'Preview(_:traits:_:body:)' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer but my is iOS 16 and most app has even 15 or lower.. so this is like not up to 2024 year even.. like maybe we could use this after 2+ years at least from now..

Comment: @KAMIKAZE Yes, `#Preview` was introduced with iOS 17. The original `PreviewProvider` structure, which was introduced with iOS 13, still exists so is fine to use if that fits with your development target. However, the original question was about how to implement one of `PreviewProvider`'s features within the new #Preview syntax.